# Django 4: Product.objects.get(id=1) returns an error "DoesNotExist" but I already have 7 products listed

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, web-deployment, django-orm

I already have 7 products listed in my DB and I can check them by `Product.objects.all()` but when I do `Product.objects.get(id=1)` or pass any id as a parameter it returns me this error:

[image]

**meanwhile, this is what I am doing:**

*`[views.py file]`*

---

### here If I use `Product.objects.all()` it returns me all my 7 products listed in DB but if I use `Product.objects.get(id=id)` it retuns me the error

```
def update_product(request, id):
product=Product.objects.get(id=id) #As far I understood, here the actual problem starts.

context = {
    "product": product
}

return render(request, "myapp/updateProduct.html", context)
```

*`[urls.py file]`*

---

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views


    app_name = "myapp"

    urlpatterns = [path('', views.index),
                   path('products/', views.products),
                   path('products/<int:id>', views.product_details, 
                                            name='product_details'),
                   path('products/add', views.add),
                   path('products/update/<int:id>', views.update_product, 
                                            name='update_product'),

                   ]
```

*`[updateProduct.html file]`*

---

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<main class="box-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Update Your Product</h1> 
    </div>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="number" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price" required>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="description" id="description" 
               placeholder="Description"> -->
        <textarea spellcheck="true" name="description" id="description" 
               placeholder="Description" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="upload" id="upload" required>
        <input type="submit" name="Add Product" value="Add Product">
    </form>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: Does `Product` with ID = 1 exists? Show Product model and maybe list of all products

Comment: Most probably that id does not exist in your db. Try to do: `for p in Product.objects.all(): print (p.id)`

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis Thank you, I just realized the id of all products is starting from 5, not sure why :/

Comment: @abhisheksurela Because you deleted the first 4 objects that you had created